# Retrieving values from 4 tables with one is to many relationship in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, foreign-keys, one-to-many

I have a blade page which should display the selected projectid's details and also that particular ids datas from other three tables, Events, Donation & Opportunity. But I'm only able to retrieve the project tables values and not the other 3 tables. No errors message as well. Please help to query all 4 tables in a single page using laravel.

My ProjectController file:

```
public function getDetailedProject()
{
    $data=Project::all()->where('pid', 35); 
    $eve=Event::all()->where('pro_id', 35);
    $don=Donation::all()->where('pro_id', 35);
    $opp=Opportunity::all()->where('pro_id', 35);
    return view('other.detailedProject')->with('data',$data);
}
```

My DetailedProject.blade.php file codes:

```
@extends('templates.default')

@section('content')

  @foreach($data as $row)   
  <ul>
<h2>Project Details</h2>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
    <label>Project Title </label>
</div>
    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9">
    <label> {{$row->ptitle}}</label>
</div>
</div>  

<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
    <label>Project Description</label>
</div>
    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9">
    <label> {{$row->pdescription}}</label>
</div>
</div>  

<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
    <label>Project Duration</label>
</div>
    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9">
    <label> {{$row->pduration}}</label>
</div>
</div> 

<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
    <label>Project Start Date</label>
</div>
    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9">
    <label> {{$row->psdate}}</label>
</div>
</div> 

<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
    <label>Project End Date</label>
</div>
    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9">
    <label> {{$row->pedate}}</label>
</div>
</div> 

<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
    <label>Project Category</label>
</div>
    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9">
    <label> {{$row->pcategory}} </label>
</div>
</div> 
@endforeach

@foreach($data as $eve)
<h2>Event Details</h2>

 <div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
    <label>Event Title </label>
</div>
    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9">
    <label> {{$eve->etitle}}</label>
</div>
</div>  

<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
    <label>Event Details</label>
</div>
    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9">
    <label> {{$eve->edetails}}</label>
</div>
</div>  

<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
    <label>Event Date</label>
</div>
    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9">
    <label> {{$eve->edate}}</label>
</div>
</div> 

<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
    <label>Event Time</label>
</div>
    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9">
    <label> {{$eve->etime}}</label>
</div>
</div> 

<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
    <label>Project End Date</label>
</div>
    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9">
    <label> {{$eve->elocation}}</label>
</div>
</div> 

<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
    <label>Event Details</label>
</div>
    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9">
    <label> {{$eve->eimage}}</label>
</div>
</div>  
@endforeach

@foreach($data as $don)
<h2>Donation</h2>

 <div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
    <label>Total Cost</label>
</div>
    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9">
    <label>{{$don->dtotal}}</label>
</div>
</div>  

<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
    <label>Amount in Hand</label>
</div>
    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9">
    <label> {{$don->dinhand}}</label>
</div>
</div>  

<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
    <label>Amount Required</label>
</div>
    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9">
    <label>{{$don->dtotal}} - {{$don->dinhand}}</label>
</div>
</div> 

<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
    <label>Bank Account</label>
</div>
    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9">
    <label> {{$don->dbankaccount}}</label>
</div>
</div> 
@endforeach

@foreach($data as $opp)
<h2>Oppertunity</h2>

 <div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
    <label>Position</label>
</div>
    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9">
    <label> {{$opp->oposition}}</label>
</div>
</div>  

<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
    <label>Describtion</label>
</div>
    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9">
    <label> {{$opp->odescription}}</label>
</div>
</div>  

<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
    <label>Location</label>
</div>
    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9">
    <label> {{$opp->olocation}}</label>
</div>
</div> 

<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
    <label>Deadlinet</label>
</div>
    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9">
    <label> {{$opp->odeadline}}</label>
</div>
</div> 
@endforeach

</ul>
@stop
```

Please help me figure out the mistake. Im new to laravel

Comment: You're only passing `$data` into the view. `$eve`, `$don` and `$opp` are not part of `$data`. At no point are you actually calling the relationships.

Comment: Don't use `all()->where()`, this gets all the data from the database and then filters the collection which is incredibly inefficient.  Use `where()->get()` to filter on the database and only get the data that matches the conditions.

Comment: I tried that but still getting error. So how should i code it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, hope it works!

```
$data=Project::where('pid', 35)->get();
$eve=Event::where('pro_id', 35)->get();
$don=Donation::where('pro_id', 35)->get();
$opp=Opportunity::where('pro_id', 35)->get();
return view('other.detailedProject', compact('data', 'eve', 'don', 'opp'));
```

Comment: i tried but got a error message. "Use of undefined constant data - assumed 'data' (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\resources\views\Other\detailedProject.blade.php)".   This one. How to solve it??